# DB2 - SQL - MERGE - An unexpected token -

Tags: db2, sql-merge

I am a beginner here so soryy for mistake :-(

I try to execute Marge but unfortunately keeps getting the same error and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```sql
MERGE INTO TB_CLIENT_ACCOUNT_LINK as A

    USING

        (SELECT client_id, account_id, PROPER_NAME
           FROM TB_CLIENT_ACCOUNT_LINK
          WHERE client_id=233176) as B

        ON (A.account_id = B.account_id)

        WHEN MATCHED THEN

        UPDATE
           SET A.PROPER_NAME = B.PROPER_NAME
         WHERE A.client_id=110966
           AND A.PROPER_NAME IS NOT NULL
```

And I had error:

`An unexpected token "where" was found following "NAME = B.PROPER_NAME". Expected tokens may include: "OVERLAPS".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=3.72.52 SQL Code: -104, SQL State: 42601`

What do I want to do?

I want to copy **PROPER_NAME** from one client to another that has the same **ACCOUNT_ID**.

I don't want to do it this way, I want to use marge or (if possible) the advanced update option.

I normally do it like this

```sql
update TB_CLIENT_ACCOUNT_LINK set PROPER_NAME = 'NAME1'
 where A.client_id=110966 and A.PROPER_NAME is not null;
update TB_CLIENT_ACCOUNT_LINK set PROPER_NAME = 'NAME2'
 where A.client_id=110966 and A.PROPER_NAME is not null;
update TB_CLIENT_ACCOUNT_LINK set PROPER_NAME = 'NAME3'
 where A.client_id=110966 and A.PROPER_NAME is not null;
```

etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the [MERGE statement](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-merge) syntax.
You have a number of mistakes in your statement.

- It's not possible to specify `WHERE` clause in the `update-operation`
- The `assignment-clause` can't contain a correlation name at the left side

Use one of the following instead.

```
MERGE INTO TB_CLIENT_ACCOUNT_LINK as A
USING
(select client_id,account_id,PROPER_NAME from TB_CLIENT_ACCOUNT_LINK where client_id=233176) as B
ON (A.account_id = B.account_id)
--AND A.client_id=110966 and A.PROPER_NAME is not null
when matched
-- Comment out the following line, if you uncommented the one above
AND A.client_id=110966 and A.PROPER_NAME is not null
then update set PROPER_NAME = B.PROPER_NAME
```

Comment: THX! For comment. Now i had a different error, which I am checking `
MERGE INTO TB_CLIENT_ACCOUNT_LINK as A

USING

(select client_id,account_id,PROPER_NAME from TB_CLIENT_ACCOUNT_LINK where client_id=233176) as B

ON (A.account_id = B.account_id)

AND A.client_id=110966 and A.PROPER_NAME is not null

then update set PROPER_NAME = B.PROPER_NAME
`

`
An unexpected token "MERGE INTO TB_CLIENT_ACCOUNT_LINK as A
USING
" was found following "BEGIN-OF-STATEMENT". Expected tokens may include: "<space>".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=3.72.52 SQL Code: -104, SQL State: 42601
`

Comment: You missed the `WHEN MATCHED` clause.

Comment: I'm embarrassed. THX!